# Show that $W$ is NOT a subsbace of $ \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$W $= {$(a,b,c):a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 0$}

As far as I have tried it with my concepts which are somewhat definitely not cleared the W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I don't know why not.

I tried the $3$ conditions that like $a = 0, b = 0, c = 0$: which gives us $0,0,0$ and multiplying with constants and then addition they all are forming a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I can't grasp the concept and also how to check if $W$ is closed under addition and subtraction the main problem is not checking its that how to use this condition or info into the question which is $a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq0$ this is the thing that is not clear

Sorry for such basic question starting Linear Algebra so need help thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong. $W=\{(0,0,0)\}$ is most certainly a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: yes that confuses me too but question says that **NOT a subspace of $R^3$**

Comment: @AliAzamRana Source?

Comment: question in homework given by Professor @GitGud

Comment: From the immediate surroundings of the problem, is it possible that he meant $W=\{(a,b,c)\colon a^2+b^2+c^2\leq r\}$, for some $r>0$?

Comment: no I can't predict or say anything like that because the statement is clear in the question and nothing more can be said about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been established in the comments, if the definition of $W$ is as written, then $W$ *is* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. To see this, note that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$ if and only if $a = b = c = 0$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
W &= \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 0\}\\ 
&= \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 0 \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 0\}\\
&= \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0\}\\
&= \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid a = b = c = 0\}\\
&= \{(0, 0, 0)\}.
\end{align*}